# Action creators handling axios get.request with state access for param

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to pass some value from a component to a action creators which is doing a get request with axios. I'm trying to follow this pattern from Dan Abramov :

```
export const SOME_ACTION = 'SOME_ACTION';
export function someAction() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {items} = getState().otherReducer;

    dispatch(anotherAction(items));
  }
}
```

However I can't make it work. I think I have trouble on two level : my component and my action creator. Would be great to have some helps.

my component :

```
const timeR = ({ 
  selectedTimeRange,
  timeRange = [],
  onTimeChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Filters:
        <div>
          Year:
          <select
            defaultValue={selectedTimeRange}
            onChange={onTimeChange}>
            <option value="all" >All</option>
            {timeRange.map((y, i) =>
              <option key={i} value={y}>{y}</option>
            )}
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    var range = ['30daysAgo', '15daysAgo', '7daysAgo'];
  return {
      selectedTimeRange: state.timeReducer.timerange[0],
      timeRange: range 
  };
};

const mapDispachToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
  onTimeChange: (e) => {dispatch (onSetTimeRange(e.target.value));},

  };
};

const TimeRange = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(timeR);

export default TimeRange;
```

This component give me a dropdown menu. When selecting a timerange, for example '30daysAgo', it update my redux store state so I can access the value from my reducer.

Here is the action associated to my dropdown menu :

```
export function onSetTimeRange(timerange) {
 return {
        type: 'SET_TIME_RANGE',
        timerange
    }
}
```

and here is the action dealing with axios.get :

```
export const fetchgadata = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST',
        isFetching:true,
        error:null
  });

var VIEW_ID = "ga:80820965";

return axios.get("http://localhost:3000/gadata", {
  params: {
    id: VIEW_ID
  }
}).then(response => {
      dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
            isFetching: false,
            data: response.data.rows.map( ([x, y]) => ({ x, y }) )
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE',
            isFetching:false,
            error:err
      });
      console.error("Failure: ", err);
    });
};
```

**My question :**

How do I bring these two actions together. At the end I would like to be able, when doing `onChange` on my drop-down menu, to call a action with the value selected from my menu as a param for my axios.get request.

I feel like I need to nest two actions creators. I've tried this but doesn't work (`"fetchgadata" is read-only` error in my terminal)

```
export const SET_TIME_RANGE = 'SET_TIME_RANGE';
export function onSetTimeRange() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {VIEW_ID} = getState().timerange;

    dispatch(fetchgadata = (VIEW_ID) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST',
        isFetching:true,
        error:null,
        id:VIEW_ID,
  });
  });

return axios.get("http://localhost:3000/gadata", {
  params: {
    id: VIEW_ID
  }
}).then(response => {
      dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
            isFetching: false,
            data: response.data.rows.map( ([x, y]) => ({ x, y }) )
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
            ype: 'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE',
            isFetching:false,
            error:err
      });
      console.error("Failure: ", err);
    });
}
  }
```

Edit:

reducers for API call :

```
const initialState = {data:null,isFetching: false,error:null};
export const gaData = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST':
        case 'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE':
        return { ...state, isFetching: action.isFetching, error: action.error };

        case 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {data: action.data, isFetching: action.isFetching,
                 error: null });
        default:return state;

    }
};
```

reducers for Drop-down :

```
const items = [{timerange: '30daysAgo'},{timerange: '15daysAgo'},{timerange: '7daysAgo'}] 

const timeReducer = (state = { 
  timerange: items 
  }, action) => { 
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_TIME_RANGE':
      console.log(state,action);
              return {
        ...state,
        timerange: action.timerange,
      };
    default:
      return state;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a little typo in the catch of your axios.get request, it reads `ype: FETCH_DATA_FAILURE`. Otherwise, can you add in your reducer for me, I don't see it up there? If I understand correctly, you want one action to update two different pieces of state, in which case you would simply dispatch an action and add it to both reducers. Really it's best to just demonstrate:

```
//axios call
axios.get("some route", { some params } )
.then(response => { 
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_TWO_THINGS,
      payload: some_value
    })
}) .... catch, etc

//reducer 1
import { UPDATE_TWO_THINGS } from 'types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { userInfo: '' };

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
   case UPDATE_TWO_THINGS:
     return {...state, userInfo: payload };
  }

  return state;
}

//reducer 2
import { UPDATE_TWO_THINGS } from 'types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { businessInfo: '' };

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
   case UPDATE_TWO_THINGS:
     return {...state, businessInfo: payload };
  }

  return state;
}
```

Hopefully this helps, but let me know if not, I'll do my best to get this working with you! Thanks for asking!

Comment: hum... I'm not sure it's really what I want. I mean I  want one action to update two different pieces of state. But I want to use the first piece of state to update the second piece of state. In my example, I need to use the timerange to update my google analytics api call. In other words `selecting a time range` -> 'passing this time range to my axios.get`... but yes I want this two step happen after on `onChange` event. Is it clearer ?

Comment: Hey Simon, sorry for taking so long to respond. What you're asking for is a bit frowned upon, and generally means you need to rethink your action/reducer relationship. Here's a great article I found that briefly explains why it's not that great of an idea, but then goes on to explain how it can be done if you're insistent. http://jamesknelson.com/join-the-dark-side-of-the-flux-responding-to-actions-with-actors/

Comment: Yes. you're right. I finally solve my issue. However I still don't really know how I did it. Just tweak with my code. Need to make all this clear before writing a proper answer.